# Return Option[DataFrame] where isDefined is false

Tags: scala

From a function, how do I create and then return an instance of `Option[DataFrame]` where `isDefined()` evaluates to false?

```
val thing = foo() 
if (thing.isDefined) {
   // result
} else {
   // do something interesting!!
}
```

Comment: `Option.empty[DataFrame]`  ?

Comment: @jwvh Can you think of any examples where `None` would be insufficient? Wouldn't it be simpler and clearer to just declare the return type explicitly?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I agree. Simpler, clearer, and sufficient. I chose that representation of `None` so as not to confuse it with `thing`, which looks like it might also be an `Option`. My question, which is not completely clear, "Is there supposed to be a direct relationship between `thing` status (defined/not) and return status (Some/None)?"

Comment: I'm quite disappointed with the StackOverflow community.  My question currently has a -1.   I've been here since the beginning, and it started out being a place where you could ask simple, straightforward questions, but no more.  It's becoming a place where only the "smart" guys are allowed to ask "smart" questions, and people starting out are not welcome.

Comment: @MedicineMan You can definitely ask simple question, but yours is rather unclear: what does `thing` have to do with anything? Do you just want to know how to conditionally return an empty `Option` (that is `None`) vs returning `Some(YourDataFrame)`?

Comment: @francoisr I want to know how to return an empty `Option`.  I've shown how I might use it, but perhaps in scala, this is not how you define functions, use variables, or use optionals.  I'm pretty early in my learning here, I have to produce and learn at the same time.   Unfortunately, we don't all have environments where we can sit back and read the docs for two weeks.

Comment: @MedicineMan, you say that you "want to know how to return an empty `Option`" and that's exactly what I proposed. (See 1st comment.) If I've misunderstood your question (as has oybek, and francoisr) then perhaps you could edit it to provide more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

if the `thing` is `Option`, then you can do it without if.

```
val thing = foo()
thing.map { th => 
  // do something interesting!!
}
```

Comment: Although this doesn't answer my question, I appreciate the input. Perhaps it would be better as a comment (?)